# How to make the Components inside a JPanel that's inside a JTable editabe?

Tags: java, swing, model, jtable

I'm trying to display a list of data in a table-like manner with the information for each item in the list to be in one row. I also want the appearance of each "cell" to look better than the default JTable, and want the data to be editable.

What I have right now is a JTable with one column, and each row is a JPanel that contains a list of JTextfields. It looks how I want it to look, but I can't edit the JTextfields.

How can I get the JTextfields to become editable? Here is the code I have now:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JTableWithJPanelExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder( BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "ODI Rankings", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP));
        String[][] data = {
           { "1", "Steve", "AUS" },
           { "2", "Virat", "IND" },
           { "3", "Kane", "NZ" },
           { "4", "David", "AUS" },
           { "5", "Ben", "ENG" },
           { "6", "Eion", "ENG" },
        };

        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new JPanelTableModel());
        table.setDefaultRenderer(JPanel.class, new JPanelRowRenderer());
        table.setRowHeight(30);
        JPanelTableModel model = (JPanelTableModel) table.getModel();

        // Add rows
        for (String[] row : data) {
            JPanel rowPanel = new JPanel();
            for (String element : row) {
                rowPanel.add(new JTextField(element));
            }
            model.addRow(rowPanel);
        }
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(550, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    private static class JPanelTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private List<JPanel> rows = new ArrayList<>();

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return JPanel.class;
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
            return "";
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return (rows == null) ? 0 : rows.size();
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return (rows == null) ? null : rows.get(rowIndex);
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int columnIndex, int rowIndex) {
            return true;
        }

        public void addRow(JPanel panel) {
            rows.add(panel);
        }

        public void clear() {
                rows.clear();
            }
    }

    private static class JPanelRowRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            return (JPanel) value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're grossly mixing your model with your view, and this is a very bad thing to do. It is fine if you want the JPanel to represent a view of the row's data, but the data itself, the table's model, should not hold any Swing components whatsoever, and to do it this way is, to be honest, quite foolish and quite wrong. Instead, have the model hold pure data, give the JTable a cell renderer *and* a cell editor that uses  your JPanel (if need be) with its JTextFields.

Comment: Just use your data to create a `DefaultTableModel`. The cells will be editable by default.

Comment: .... but a DefaultTableModel based on the Strings/ints or other lower-level data, not based on GUI elements

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, should have said "data variable". The "data" variable is a 2D array containing String data.

Comment: You need to provide a TableCellEditor as mentioned by – @Hovercraft Full Of Eels . your table provides a editor based on the column class provided by getColumnClass() in your table model and there is no editor for JPanel.class . See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html then apply that to your columns as table.getCoumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor() or something similar

Comment: @RVISHAL: the code needs a decent non-view model and a cell editor, as you mentioned, but also needs a cell renderer.

Comment: He did provide a cell renderer JPanelRowRenderer and his tableModel though not clean will work for now. I guess :/

Comment: @RVISHAL: it's not a valid one though. Again, the main problem with this code, with his thought process is that his model is fully corrupt and is fighting *against* the library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Again, I strongly urge you to separate model from view. The model should be storable as pure data, should be viewed in many different ways if need be, and so should not be so closely tied to the view.

So, assuming similar data, ...

```
    String[][] data = { 
            { "1", "Steve", "AUS" }, 
            { "2", "Virat", "IND" }, 
            { "3", "Kane", "NZ" },
            { "4", "David", "AUS" }, 
            { "5", "Ben", "ENG" }, 
            { "6", "Eion", "ENG" } };
```

let's build a better model

Let's create a class to hold 1 row's worth of data:

```
public class RowData {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String countryCode;

    public RowData(int id, String name, String countryCode) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RowData [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", countryCode=" + countryCode + "]";
    }

}
```

And then use this to create a table model. I've extended a DefaultTableModel and held a single row's data as a single row in the model. This in reality it is a 1D collection of data:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    private static final Object[] COLUMN_NAMES = new Object[] { "ODI Rankings" };

    public MyTableModel() {
        super(COLUMN_NAMES, 0);
    }

    public void addRow(RowData rowData) {
        super.addRow(new Object[] { rowData });
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex != 0) {
            String text = "for column index: " + columnIndex;
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(text);
        } else {
            return RowData.class;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the key for your problem is to create a renderer and an editor that will display the data in a JPanel that holds 3 JTextFields (as it appears you desire), so an renderer that works could be:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyCellRenderer extends JPanel implements TableCellRenderer {
    private JTextField idField = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField countryCodeField = new JTextField(10);

    public MyCellRenderer() {
        add(idField);
        add(nameField);
        add(countryCodeField);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        RowData rowData = (RowData) value;
        if (rowData != null) {
            idField.setText("" + rowData.getId());
            nameField.setText(rowData.getName());
            countryCodeField.setText(rowData.getCountryCode());
        } else {
            idField.setText("");
            nameField.setText("");
            countryCodeField.setText("");
        }
        if (isSelected) {
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 1));
        } else {
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
        }
        return this;
    }

}
```

and an editor (that builds off of the default cell editor):

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private JTextField idField = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField countryCodeField = new JTextField(10);
    private RowData currentData;

    public MyCellEditor() {
        mainPanel.add(idField);
        mainPanel.add(nameField);
        mainPanel.add(countryCodeField);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        int id = 0;
        try {
            id = Integer.parseInt(idField.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return currentData;
            // warn user here
        }
        String name = nameField.getText();
        String countryCode = countryCodeField.getText();
        RowData rowData = new RowData(id, name, countryCode);
        return rowData;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        currentData = (RowData) value;
        if (currentData != null) {
            idField.setText("" + currentData.getId());
            nameField.setText(currentData.getName());
            countryCodeField.setText(currentData.getCountryCode());
        }
        return mainPanel;
    }
}
```

---

---

The remaining driving code with imports, plus a class that extends JTable to fix a row height problem:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JTableWithJPanelExample2 extends JPanel {
    private MyTableModel tableModel = new MyTableModel();
    private MyTable table = new MyTable(tableModel);

    public JTableWithJPanelExample2() {
        MyCellRenderer rendererEditor = new MyCellRenderer();
        table.setDefaultRenderer(RowData.class, rendererEditor);
        table.setDefaultEditor(RowData.class, new MyCellEditor());
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "ODI Rankings",
                TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    public void addRow(RowData rowData) {
        tableModel.addRow(rowData);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] data = { 
                { "1", "Steve", "AUS" }, 
                { "2", "Virat", "IND" }, 
                { "3", "Kane", "NZ" },
                { "4", "David", "AUS" }, 
                { "5", "Ben", "ENG" }, 
                { "6", "Eion", "ENG" } };
        JTableWithJPanelExample2 example = new JTableWithJPanelExample2();
        for (String[] datum : data) {
            int id = Integer.parseInt(datum[0]);
            String name = datum[1];
            String countryCode = datum[2];
            RowData rowData = new RowData(id, name, countryCode);
            example.addRow(rowData);
        }

        JFrame gui = new JFrame("GUI");
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.add(example);
        gui.pack();
        gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyTable extends JTable {
    public MyTable(MyTableModel tableModel) {
        super(tableModel);
    }

    // a kludge to make the cells high enough to display properly
    @Override
    public int getRowHeight() {
        return 2 * super.getRowHeight();
    }
}
```

I would assume that the GUI would eventually be tied into a database, and using a more pure model would make it much easier, cleaner, and safer to do so, including to transfer data from the database to the model and from the model into the database. Again, this just makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, I got this example to work. The only issue is that I can't edit the table with only the keyboard, but I'll see if I can figure out how to get that to work.

Comment: Amazing work as always. A suggestion I may add is to create a seperate class which contains a panel and 3 textfields and reuse that one instance in both the renderer and editor to save memory.

Answer (score 0):

Well this was a complete mess and I would not recommend this approach as @Hovercraft Full Of Eels stated 'You just can't mix your view and model'. But this is what worked.

Step 1
Make sure your TableModel and editor share the same rows (just my suggestion).

```
private static class JPanelTableModel extends AbstractTableModel 
{
  private List<JPanel> rows = new ArrayList<>();

  public Editor editor(){return new Editor(rows);}
}
```

Step 2

Create your own cell editor for your JPanel class.

```
    private static class Editor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor 
    {
     private List<JPanel> rows;
     private int row;
     
     private Editor(List<JPanel> rows){this.rows=rows;}
     
     public Object getCellEditorValue(){return rows.get(row);}//Return the value of the current row you are editing
     
     @Override
     public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
     {
      this.row=row;
      
      return rows.get(row);//Simple Return that exact same row you passed to your tableRenderer so that Your table makes it ready to receive user focus and input
     }
    }
```

Step 3
Make it the default editor for your table.

```
JPanelTableModel model=new JPanelTableModel();
table.setModel(model);
table.setDefaultRenderer(JPanel.class, new JPanelRowRenderer());
table.setDefaultEditor(JPanel.class,model.editor());//This is what matters
table.setRowHeight(30);
```

Not clean but it will do. I highly suggest you refactor your code just to return 'Light Weight Child Components' and not 'Heavy Weight Containers' as individual cell components.

For your purpose since the table just has one column I suggest just using an JPanel with an `BoxLayout` along the `Y_AXIS` to display your rows.

Comment: again not recommended just putting it out there

Comment: How do you add data to the table in this case?

Comment: You are already doing it. List<Panel>rows is your data and it is shared by your editor and your TableModel. Either you can continue to use this approach or you can just use addRow()[DefaultTableModel] & getValue(row,col)[JTable] to store data.

Comment: This is not good as it again mixes the model with the view, cannot be maintained in any reasonable fashion and absolutely should not be recommended. Any viable solution should start with a correct model. Period.

Comment: I feel obligated to post a more correct answer, and have posted one that I think addresses everything

Comment: @RVISHAL my answer is mainly for you. Please comment if you agree/disagree that it is a better solution than your proposed one, or have anything to add

Comment: Off course your answer is much more refined than mine. I was just just focusing on making a quick solution so yes upvoted